# Limit to number of emails in each batch from SendGrid

Tags: sendgrid

I am trying to send batches of emails through SendGrid from my Azure database.
There seems to be a limit of 1,000 per batch so we are having to code in batches of 1,000.  Is there a way round this.
Thanks
Pauline

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Sendgrid's bulk email API documentation you cannot send more than 1000 email's in a batch. Currently, you may make up to 10,000 requests per second to Sendgrid's endpoint. Each email you send may include up to 1000 recipients - [Mail Send overview](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html#-Limitations)

However, there is a way you can get rid of the this batch system. My recommendation would be to utilize [SendGrid's marketing campaigns](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/index.html) feature.

A typical flow would be:

- Upload your contacts to SendGrid. You can also include custom fields with each contact which can be used for personalizing the content (simple example would be: Dear %first_name%).
- you can either add the desired contacts to a list or you can define a query (called "segment") to match the desired contacts. For example: "all contacts where country=Canada".
- you create the campaign by specifying your HTML and text content, what IP pool you want to use (assuming you purchased IP addresses from SendGrid), what lists(s) and/or segment(s) you want to use, etc.
- finally, you either send the campaign immediately or schedule it to be sent at a later date/time. The API call for sending/scheduling the campaign completes immediately but behind the scene SendGrid will take care of sending your emails which may take a while.

Taken the above text directly from Github - [Link](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/660#issuecomment-360553420) from [Jericho](https://github.com/Jericho)